# htaccess for static php files

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am struggling to get my .htaccess file working properly on my GoDaddy web hosting.

I want my URL's to be like:

www.way360group.com/about-us/ -> about-us.php
www.way360group.com/latest-projects/ -> latest-projects.php

and so on...

Here's my current .htaccess code

```html
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
 <IfModule mod_expires.c>
  ExpiresActive On
  ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
  ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
  ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
  ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
  ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
  ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 month"
  ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
  ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
  ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
  ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
  ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"
 </IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##


# force ssl
RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]


# Redirect from http://www to http://
    RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /
        RewriteCond ${HTTPS} off
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]


# Rewrite URLs
 RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule   ^contact?$  contact.php 
    
  RewriteRule   ^what-is-corporate-social-responsibility?$  what-is-corporate-social-responsibility.php 
    
  RewriteRule   ^about-us?$  about-us.php 
    
  RewriteRule   ^latest-projects?$  latest-projects.php 
    
  RewriteRule   ^join-our-newsletter?$  join-our-newsletter.php
```

I've digged many different posts but couldn't work out a solution.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The positioning in .htaccess is really important. Since you have [L] flag, that marks it as last, so if you get any URL it will redirect to https:// and as the [L] flag the .htaccess won't go further, since the rule is valid and it will stop there.

If you are using [L] flag make sure you put those rules last, so any other rule can be checked before that one.

Also you might be lacking a bit of conditions for the rules, since your only condition is that the HTTPS is off.

On the other hand the rest of the rules you wrote seem alright.

For anything else you can look at this site for more insight [here](https://mediatemple.net/community/products/dv/204643270/using-htaccess-rewrite-rules)

Here's an example of one of the .htaccess'es that I use

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

        # force ssl
        RewriteEngine On
                RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$
                RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

    # Redirect from http://www to http://
    RewriteEngine On
                RewriteBase /
                RewriteCond ${HTTPS} off
                RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
                RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Hope that will clear it up a little (of what I was talking about earlier in the post). Also when you are coding try to leave comments behind (you can see my # comments in .htaccess), it will be helpful later on when you revisit the code after some time, so you know what's where or if someone new comes to work with you, will be much easier for them.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I moved things around and it didn't get any change. Also, if I type in way360group.com/latest-projects/ (with a slash at the end) it gives me an error message.

Comment: The error message might be 'cos it's looking at it as a folder if you add last slash, instead of .php file, since the trailing could lead the browser to think it's a folder.

Comment: I entered all I currently have on my .htaccess - not sure if GoDaddy servers might have a problem with it as well... but still, Slashes are not being inserted.